# Increase the width of Chrome tabs / display the title instantly

Tags: google-chrome

I work on Chrome with 2 to 3 tabs and the title of these are keep changing on various processes running in the background.

Now the situation is that the titles are quite long and I need to keep track of them.
By default, Chrome tab show the title through a label when we hover on it for more than 4 seconds. But the application changes title in less than that time. Now I can handle these by coding in our application, but other users can't do the same.

Is it possible to increase the width of the title of Chrome tabs?

Otherwise, is there a way to set Chrome to display the label instantly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this would be by touching the source code of Chrome, which I highly recommend to avoid.

Otherwise, I don't think it is possible to change the tab width settings/ display time of the hovering label from Chrome's settings.

Even using the experiments section of Chrome(using chrome://flags/), we can't do the same. 
But do keep an eye on the upcoming updates if this feature ever comes up.

Answer (score 2):

Google Canary this option is available, Google Canary (https://www.google.com/chrome/canary/) you can use Dev builds

after installation set the chrome flags
open Chrome canary and go to chrome://flags
Search for Scrollable TabStrip
From the drop-down menu next to Scrollable TabStrip, select Enabled there are 3 four additional options medium width, large width
use those